# Printing each file separately from a directory?

Tags: python, character-encoding, io, directory

I have a folder full of opinions in .txt files, i would like to read the complete folder and print each rawtext.txt in a format that let me read them one by one. How could i aproach this task?. Also when i read the complete folder with:

```
import os
DIR = r"/Users/user/Desktop/OpinionsTXT"
opiniones = [open(os.path.join(DIR, f)).read() for f in os.listdir(DIR)]
print opiniones
```

this is the output string:

```
f qu\xe9 suplicio, recordando cuando lo hab\xeda tenido que hacer durante unas
```

The texts are full of accents and spanish ortographic symbols, how to print them correctly?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to list all files of a directory in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207219/how-to-list-all-files-of-a-directory-in-python)

Comment: `for f in os.listdir(DIR): print open(os.path.join(DIR, f)).read() `

Answer (score 2):

What encoding is used for the files? It looks like ISO-8859-1.

In Python 2, for example, you can use `.decode('iso-8859-1')`, i.e.

```
import os
DIR = r"/Users/user/Desktop/OpinionsTXT"
opiniones = [open(os.path.join(DIR, f)).read().decode('iso-8859-1') for f in os.listdir(DIR)]
>>> print opiniones[0]   # note that opiniones is a list.
f qué suplicio, recordando cuando lo había tenido que hacer durante unas
```

Or you could open the file with the [codecs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#module-codecs) module:

```
opiniones = [codecs.open(os.path.join(DIR, f), mode='r', encoding='iso-8859-1').read() for f in os.listdir(DIR)]
```

The above is for Python 2. For Python 3 you can specify the file encoding when you open the file using the `encoding` flag.

Comment: In python 2.6 or later, the io module (io.open) lets you specifiy encoding also.